# Find $log_{P}R$ on this Elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

[The assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYHtO.png)

[image: 3 b c]

[image: Defeniton of the logaritm on an Elliptic curve]
(I also added the defenition of logaritm on Elliptic curves)

I should somehow be able to use the information from problem 3b to solve 3c efficiently but I don't know how. Could someone tell me how i could use the information in b to solve c efficient?

Comment: @Moo yes, I have done that.

Comment: If I
 understood your notation properly, the naive approach is to find $k$ such that $k P = R$. Doing this, we find that $37 P = R$. Now, how did you learn to do Discrete Logs from the given?

Comment: @Moo "how did you learn to do Discrete Logs from the given?" I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but I'm going to assume you ask if your definiton of logs is the same as the one I've learned, if that's correct then yes that is the same definiton I have learned.

Comment: @Moo I don't know what DLP is, but the reason why I ask how to use 3b is that in the solution for this exam they say "We solve the linear system and get logP R = 37" which makes me think that they use b somehow to solve problem c efficient, as checking all the points 1 to 37 seems to take ages if you don't have acces to some sort of Elliptic curve calculator, which you obvious do not have on the exam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying the second equation by 2 we have the system
\begin{align*}
6P+2Q+R=\infty, \\
4P+2Q+4R=\infty.
\end{align*}
Subtracting the second from the first gives $2P-3R=\infty$, i.e. $2P=3R$. Since $N=109$, $R = aP$ where $a\equiv3^{-1}\cdot 2\bmod{109}$. As Moo points out, this gives $a\equiv37\bmod{109}$.